# How to increase kg per hr capacity of screw press to achieve the same applied pressure per unit volume of raw material?

Tags: torque

The current capacity of screw press is only 100 kg/hr. Motor is 22kw, shaft RPM is 16, applied torque is 13,120 Nm, theoretical volume is 0.000967 cu m.

1. Am I correct to say the press is going = 13,120 Nm divided by 0.000967 cu m will get the pressure Nm/cu m?
2. If it is ok how can I increase the capacity to meet the same applied pressure equal to above answer?

Regards,

Romy

Comment: Increase either the volume delivered per turn at the same speed or increase the rpm for the same volume per turn.

Comment: $Nm/m^3 = N/m^2$ which is force per unit area, the definition of pressure.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to calculate the pressure,

A first estimate, ignoring friction, which can be substantial is,

$ F_{screw}= T/(r*tan (\alpha)) \quad$ r is screw radius , a is pitch angle.

P= F/area of press.
by increasing the motor rpm, or increasing the screw pitch you can increase the output, if your motor has enough power.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer gave the equation.

Your question is about *how*, though, so that is different. The key things you need to improve are:

1. Find better materials. Consider composites that withstand more load.
2. Increase the power of the motor.
3. Use a smaller volume per area raw material if your only goal is to increase the pressure per area.

Maybe just explain what you are making or find similar designs that worked.